# How to implement lifecycle methods in functional components in React?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

For a simple component written like this:

```
import React from 'react'

const MyComponent = ({text}) => {
    return(<div> {text} </div>
}
```

Is there a syntax for implementing lifecycle method like componentDidMount() or do I have to convert code to React.Component class?

Comment: it has to be a class to have access to the life cycle methods

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a syntax for implementing lifecycle method like componentDidMount()

No.

> do I have to convert code to React.Component class?

Yes.

See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

In the alpha version of React there is an opt in feature called hooks which will address this. See more on hooks here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html